# Update dataset from multiple table in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working on windows form application i have a  data grid view which is filling from table user rights, I am using command builder and its updating the table, all is working fine , but now i have to display the menu name from menus table in that grid view and update user rights table with command builder update method  how to achieve that  please guide me 
here is my code

```
  Public Sub ShowData()

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT MenuID,chkadd, chkedit, chkdel, chkprint, chkview FROM UserRights where userID = 'Admin'", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    myDA = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    'Automatically generates DeleteCommand, UpdateCommand and InsertCommand for DataAdapter object  
    Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(myDA)
    myDataSet = New DataSet()
    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "UserRights")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("UserRights").DefaultView
    con.Close()
    con = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.myDA.Update(Me.myDataSet.Tables("UserRights"))
    Me.myDataSet.AcceptChanges()
End Sub
```

menus table contains menuID,menuName,menuText,programID and userrights table contains   userID,menuID,programID,chkadd,chkdel,chkedit,chkprint,chkview

i want to display menuName in grid view with data from userrights

Comment: I'm not sure did I understand well Your question : You want join fields from two, or more, tables and show them in datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling values from just 1 table in your sql query instead of calling 2 tables.U need to use JOIN if you want to display result from both table.For example,you need to have a column named "MenuName" in your userrights table too.So far your userrights table contains userID,menuID,programID,chkadd,chkdel,chkedit,chkprint,chkview.After adding the column "MenuName" in userrights table,
you can use SQL JOIN query to display the column named "MenuName" and display the result in your datagridview.Hope that helps.